# Not being able to use SQLite adapter.Update()

Tags: sqlite

When I started SQLite, I always used `INSERT INTO BPO (DinY, M, S, X) VALUES` to post data to a SQLite table. That worked well.

For the last month or so I have been trying to make `adapter.Update()` work, with no success whatever, despite very long searches.
I open the connection, create a command, create an adapter and then `adapter.Update()` which does not work. 
Most grateful for a solution to what is probably a simple problem.

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here for anyone to help you. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips.

Comment: string ConnectionSource = "Data Source = TableMain.sqlite; Version = 3;";
SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionSource);
dbConnection.Open();
SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table1", dbConnection);
SQLiteCommandBuilder builder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter);

adapter.Update(table);

Answer (score 0):

Post your code, or you can test my and compare, what are you doing wrong.

SQLite samples (with DataReader, EF and Simple.Data)
https://github.com/zchpit/SQLiteSamples

SQLite mono sample (with DataReader)
https://github.com/zchpit/SqliteMonoSample